# Databricks Delta table load take long time to load 1 recod

Tags: apache-spark, databricks

Whenever databricks notebook is running, I am trying to insert 1 records into a delta table but this is taking around 70 seconds. I am passing start_time as a variable.

```
val batchDf= Seq((1000, 40, start_time, null, null, status)).toDF("Key", "RunId", "Start_Time", "End_Time", "Duration", "In-progress")

batchDf.write.format("delta").mode("append").saveAsTable("t_audit")
```

Any idea why loading 1 record into a delta table is taking this long? I would expect this to finish in less than 5 secs.

Answer (score 0):

Databricks is horribly slow in comparison to anything that I have used in the past 30 years, but in your case it could be related to [auto optimize](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/optimizations/auto-optimize.html)

Comment: thanks! it did not help though! any other table format better than Delta?

Comment: Delta is based on Parquet format, you may want to try writing Parquet format instead to see if it improves performance.